# Easier way to squash commits that will later fork into multiple branches?

Tags: git

Let's use the following example, assuming it's unreasonable to merge branch 1 and 2 in the future (for example, branch 1 is for Windows, branch 2 is for MacOS).

```
A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E ---> F (branch1)
                      \
                       \
                        G --> H --> I (branch2)
```

Say I want to squash C to B. If I understand it correctly, git rebase at F will results in following pattern:

```
A ---> BC ---> D' ---> E' ---> F' (branch1)
 \
  \
   B ---> C --> D --> G --> H --> I (branch2)
```

But since changes represented by (BC, D') and (B, C, D) are identical, I think it's reasonable to want something like this:

```
A ---> BC ---> D' ---> E' ---> F' (branch1)
                \
                 \
                  G' --> H' --> I' (branch2)
```

This seems achieveable, by creating temporary branch at D' and D, named branchD' and branchD, and then `git rebase --onto branchD branchD' branch2`.

But isn't the entire process, which includes two rebase, two branch creation too complex? What if there're 10 branches from D, which might further fork into more branches?

Is there a general way to squash 2 commits, without considering painstakingly how to make every branch inherit the squashed commit? After all, since (B, C) and BC represents same operations, I believe it's fair to ask for a context-free squash operation:

```
before squash: merge from many branches ---> B --> C ---> fork into many branches
                      \                                          /
                       \                                        /
                        \_____ there could be bypass here _____/
```

```
after squash: merge from many branches --------> BC --------> fork into many branches
                      \                                          /
                       \                                        /
                        \_____ there could be bypass here _____/
```

I'm new to git, and sorry if some understanding went wrong or there's very obvious answer.

Comment: This is replace/filter-branch territory, and will rewrite all commit ids that trace to the new ancestry. Git lets you rewrite history arbitrarily and easily, but it makes it impossible to conceal that you've done so from anyone who has the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rebase all the branches to get the squashed commits.

What you are wanting is not really feasible.  What is the number of commits that git should look at for equivalency?  Suppose your rebase also removed 2 commits along with squashing.  The history was A -> B -> Z -> X -> C -> D
where X is undoing what happened in Z so that the net result is the same as your post.  How would git know how far along the history to go for equivalency?

In general, the rebase that you are asking about is one that I would seek to avoid.  The only reason to want to do this would be if there was an extremely large file or sensitive data in the history.  Otherwise, I would just leave the history alone.